# Using variables in link_to :confirm

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, link-to, confirm

I want to use variables in the `confirm` message in `link_to`

```
<%= link_to 'DESTROY!', @user, :confirm => "are you sure you want to delete #{@user.name}"%>
```

this doesn't seem to work and it prints `"are you sure you want to delete #{@user.name}"`

How do I use variables in the confirm message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a ruby string, confirm has nothing to do with it, are you sure you have double quotes in your actual code? It's not interpolating which is what happens when you have single quotes.